# Using DISTINCT and COUNT in MySQL for over a specific value

Tags: mysql, count

I am using a Database of Artist, Album and their Tracks.

Here I am trying to print the number of track records each AlbumId has:

```
SELECT COUNT(AlbumId) as num, AlbumId
FROM Tracks
GROUP BY AlbumId
```

**Output is**

```
+-----+---------+
| num | AlbumId |
+-----+---------+
|  10 |       1 |
|   1 |       2 |
|   3 |       3 |
|   8 |       4 |
|  15 |       5 |
|  13 |       6 |
|  12 |       7 |
|  14 |       8 |
|   8 |       9 |
|  14 |      10 |
+-----+---------+
```

What I want is the list of AlbumId whose count value(num) is greater than 12. How do I do that??

For my answer, I want output something like:

```
+-----------+
|  AlbumId  |
+-----------+
|   5       |
|   6       |
|   8       |
|   10      |
+-----------+
```

Comment: Add `HAVING num > 12`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select num, AlbumId from
(SELECT COUNT(AlbumId) as num, AlbumId
FROM Tracks
GROUP BY AlbumId) a
where num >= 12
```

Comment: Can you tell me what that 'a' is doing??
That's the only thing not making sense to me

Comment: you just need to give a name to (select....) table - so I called it 'a'